# How to compile "not-main" (only .hpp) files with makefile in C++?

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm developing a parallel project with a `Main.cpp` and a set of `.hpp` files. I've found the `Makefile` below suitable to compile, deploy and execute my project on a Xeon Phi. The problem here is that if I edit only one of the `.hpp` (so not `Main.cpp`) then when I execute `make compile` obviously nothing happens (so I have to execute `make clean` before). Can you help me to change it so if I edit `file.hpp` then it will compile it? Thanks!

```
FF_ROOT     = /home/luca/fastflow
BOOST_ROOT  = /home/luca/boost_1_59_0
CC      = icpc -mmic
CXX     = $(CC) -std=c++11 -DNO_DEFAULT_MAPPING
INCLUDES    = -I $(BOOST_ROOT) -I $(FF_ROOT) 
CXXFLAGS    = 

LDFLAGS     = -pthread
OPTFLAGS    = -O3 -finline-functions -DNDEBUG -g -O0

TARGETS     =               \
        Main                \

.PHONY: all clean copy exec cleanall
.SUFFIXES: .cpp 

%: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $(OPTFLAGS) -o $@ $< $(LDFLAGS)

all: compile

compile: $(TARGETS)

copy:   
        scp $(TARGETS) mic0:
exec:   
        ssh mic0 './$(TARGETS) $(ARGS)'
clean: 
        rm -f $(TARGETS)
cleanall    : clean
        \rm -f *.o *~
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Makefile is blatantly *not sufficient*. At the moment it only contains the *commands* to translate from one input to the next, but it's missing the crucial ingredient of any build system: Dependencies.

Dependencies are hard to maintain by hand. You could add `main: a.hpp b.hpp` etc by hand, but that doesn't scale and you forget to update it when you refactor. That's why `make` is not usually something the user should use directly. `make` is a bit like assembler: it's the final level at which build rules are expressed, but creating the build rules is best left to a higher-level system (e.g. automake or cmake or any of the other competitors in the field; or even the old `makedepend`).

---

As a side note, you really don't want to build the binary directly from source, that defeats almost all points of having a Makefile. You really want to break your project into separately compiled translation units, so that you only rebuild the minimal amount after a change.

```
OBJS := a.o b.o c.o

main: $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $< -o $@

.cc.o:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

# Dependencies! This is in addition to the implied "foo.o: foo.cc" above.

a.o: a.h b.h tools.h
b.o: b.h tools.h
c.o: c.h b.h weirdstuff.h
```

Many [tutorials](http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/howto_makefiles.html) explain all this.

Comment: Here's a short [demo](http://pastebin.com/rn5wVxxm): Run `make setup` and then `make` (in an empty directory).

Answer (score 0):

Add a rule for the source file where it depends on all (local, not system) header files.

Like

```
Main.cpp: SomeHeaderFile.hpp SomeOtherHeaderFile.hpp
```