# Different makefiles produce different error outputs?

Tags: c++, eclipse, makefile, eclipse-cdt

I'm developing a parallel map/reduce project. The first `makefile` that I've written was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34351767/how-to-compile-not-main-only-hpp-files-with-makefile-in-c/34351861#34351861).

Then I've followed [this](http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/howto_makefiles.html) tutorial (suggested in my linked question) and this is the new `makefile`:

```
#
# 'make depend' uses makedepend to automatically generate dependencies 
#               (dependencies are added to end of Makefile)
# 'make'        build executable file 'mycc'
# 'make clean'  removes all .o and executable files
#

#Fastflow and Boost paths
FF_ROOT     = /home/luca/fastflow
BOOST_ROOT  = /home/luca/boost_1_59_0

# compiler
CC = icpc -mmic

# compiler flag
CXX = $(CC) -std=c++11 -DNO_DEFAULT_MAPPING

# compile-time flags
CFLAGS =

# header files other than /usr/include
INCLUDES = -I$(FF_ROOT)  -I$(BOOST_ROOT)

# define any libraries to link into executable:
LIBS = -pthread

#optimization flags
OPTFLAGS = -O3 -finline-functions -DNDEBUG -g -O0

# define the C source files
SRCS = Main.cpp

# define the C object files 
OBJS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)

# define the executable file 
MAIN = mapreduce


.PHONY: all depend clean

all:    $(MAIN)
    @echo  Simple compiler named mycc has been compiled

$(MAIN): $(OBJS) 
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $(OPTFLAGS) -o $(MAIN) $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

.cpp.o:
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $<  -o $@

clean:
    $(RM) *.o *~ $(MAIN)

depend: $(SRCS)
    makedepend $(INCLUDES) $^

# DO NOT DELETE THIS LINE -- make depend needs it

Main.o: /home/luca/fastflow/ff/pipeline.hpp
Main.o: /home/luca/fastflow/ff/svector.hpp /usr/include/stdlib.h
Main.o: /usr/include/features.h /usr/include/stdc-predef.h
Main.o: /usr/include/alloca.h /home/luca/fastflow/ff/fftree.hpp
Main.o: /home/luca/fastflow/ff/node.hpp
Main.o: /home/luca/fastflow/ff/platforms/platform.h
Main.o: /home/luca/fastflow/ff/platforms/liblfds.h /usr/include/assert.h
Main.o: /usr/include/stdio.h /usr/include/libio.h /usr/include/_G_config.h
Main.o: /usr/include/wchar.h /home/luca/fastflow/ff/cycle.h
Main.o: /usr/include/time.h /home/luca/fastflow/ff/utils.hpp
Main.o: /usr/include/string.h /home/luca/fastflow/ff/spin-lock.hpp
Main.o: /home/luca/fastflow/ff/sysdep.h /home/luca/fastflow/ff/config.hpp
Main.o: /home/luca/fastflow/ff/buffer.hpp /home/luca/fastflow/ff/ubuffer.hpp
Main.o: /home/luca/fastflow/ff/dynqueue.hpp /home/luca/fastflow/ff/mapper.hpp
Main.o: /home/luca/fastflow/ff/mapping_utils.hpp /usr/include/errno.h
Main.o: /home/luca/fastflow/ff/barrier.hpp
Main.o: /home/luca/fastflow/ff/ocl/clEnvironment.hpp
Main.o: /home/luca/fastflow/ff/farm.hpp /home/luca/fastflow/ff/lb.hpp
Main.o: /home/luca/fastflow/ff/gt.hpp /home/luca/fastflow/ff/multinode.hpp
Main.o: MapReduceJob.hpp TaskScheduler.hpp InterValueTask.hpp
Main.o: InterValueResult.hpp Result.hpp Task.hpp RecordReader.hpp
Main.o: MapReduceWorker.hpp MapResult.hpp LineRecordReader.hpp
Main.o: TextInputFormat.hpp /home/luca/fastflow/ff/parallel_for.hpp
Main.o: /home/luca/fastflow/ff/parallel_for_internals.hpp /usr/include/math.h
Main.o: InputFormat.hpp MapTask.hpp
```

**Here's the the problem:** when I execute the binary file produced by the first makefile the following (correct) error message is printed:

```
ERROR: FARM, try to add zero workers!
```

And this is the (odd) error message printed by executing the new binary file:

```
mapreduce: /home/luca/fastflow/ff/farm.hpp:1753: ff::ff_Farm<IN_t, OUT_t>::ff_Farm(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ff::ff_node> >&&, ff::ff_node&, bool) [with IN_t = char; OUT_t = char]: Assertion `nw>0' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

**In addiction** the Eclipse CDT debugger works fine with the old makefile, while with the new one this error message is printed:

```
Can't find a source file at "/build/buildd/eglibc-2.19/signal/../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c" 
Locate the file or edit the source lookup path to include its location.
```

Am I doing something wrong with the new makefile?

Comment: No, but I need to compile my project on a Xeon phi, with an Intel compiler. Using cmake or autotools could be "dangerous".

Comment: @user3159253 Hand writing makefiles is hard, but also very rewarding: it gives you a really good insight on th build process, and once you master make for software building, you start to use it for a lot of different stuff !

Comment: Unless I missed something, this is not a problem related to `make` but related to the app your are building. And why are you calling makefile through Eclipse ? Did you try through the shell ? Could you clarify.

Comment: Folks, I've been writing Makefiles since early 90-s, my latest accepted answer on SO is about Makefiles. And that was the reason I asked if @justHelloWorld really needs this way of sorrow :-)

Comment: @user3159253 , no offense ! Hey, I didn't check your profile before my comment. While I agree with you for the "rookie" situation, I'm sure you also agree with me on long-term ;-)

Comment: And yes, I'm agree with @kebs, the root of the problem is in sources, not in makefiles. The "odd" error message is the output from failed [assert](http://linux.die.net/man/3/assert). Frequently a crash follows such a line.

Comment: I'd suggest to run the program under a debugger, so you could inspect what goes wrong. Or, better, if you actually have the coredump from that failed run (look for a file called `core` in the current directory), then you could load that coredump into `gdb` and inspect "postmortal" conditions of your program.

Comment: @kebs remanining in Eclipse is quickier. However I tried on the shell, also, same message. However, the thing that made me think about something about bad compilation/makefile, is the fact that the Eclipse debugger doesn't run with new makefile. What do you think about it?